# Only match \n if surrounded by letters

Tags: python, regex

I'm attempting to pull some data with BS4, but I'm having som difficulties with what is returned. I need some regex to remove '\n' from strings, but only when it is surrounded by letters, or when it's not at the beginning or end of the string.

Example:

```
\nLorem ipsum do\nlor sit amet \n
```

I would want that to return as:

```
\nLorem ipsum dolor sit amet \n
```

Regex is like black magic to me so every attempt I've made has matched too much or nothing at all.

What I've tried:

https://regex101.com/r/opRffh/3 - which matches 'o\nl', one to many characters on either side.

What regular expression should I use to accomplish this?

Comment: how are you gonna decide which /n is between string and which /n is surrounding string? Your algorithm will depend much on the kind of string. It will be better if you provide a good case of the string you are trying to format.

Comment: [You may use this regex](https://regex101.com/r/opRffh/4)

Comment: Hint: use split("\n") and thereafter reconstruct string using for-loop with an if-statement that selects if item from list is "'\n". Once you get the hang on that you can experiment with regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lookarounds while matching `\n`:

```
(?<=[a-zA-Z])\n(?=[a-zA-Z])
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/opRffh/4)

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=[a-zA-Z])`: Lookbehind to assert that we have a letter at previous position
- `\n`: Match newline
- `(?=[a-zA-Z])`: Lookahead to assert that we have a letter at next position

**Code:**

```
>>> str = ("\n"
...     "Lorem ipsum do\n"
...     "lor sit amet \n")
>>> print re.sub(r"(?<=[a-zA-Z])\n(?=[a-zA-Z])", '', str)

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

>>>
```

Comment: This does exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!